# Serverless Offline - Unable to Hit Endpoints When Running On MacBook 16" M1 Pro (running Mac OS Monterey)

Tags: node.js, macos, serverless, apple-m1

I have a serverless node project that I am unable to run locally successfully using serverless-offline when running on my new MacBook 16 with the M1 Pro chip.

I have installed NVM and Node in the Rosetta terminal and can run the project, but when I use Postman to hit any of the endpoints, I get a 403 error, and nothing in the console for my serverless project indicates that the endpoints were hit.  When I run the project locally, it shows that it's listening on the specified port, 5000, and no errors.

I should note that this project runs flawlessly on my older MacBook Pro (2015 mid year edition).  I have read that there are some incompatibility issues with serverless offline and Node 14, so I've tried running with Node 16 and Node 12, and neither result in a different outcome.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was specific to running on port 5000.  Mac OS Monterey uses port 5000 for AirPlay.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have been struggling with this!